# Eager loading an associated entity on the model definition with sequelizejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a many-to-many relationship defined with SequelizeJS like so:

```
global.db.User.hasMany(global.db.Role, { as: 'UserRoles', joinTableName:'user_roles'});
global.db.Role.hasMany(global.db.User, { as: 'RoleUsers', joinTableName:'user_roles'});
```

I need to ALWAYS have the roles of any user retrieved already with the user object. Is there some way to define that sort of thing when defining the model for User rather than just when calling find or find all?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when defining your model you should play with [Getters & setters](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/models#getters---setters) so that automates querying to `user_role` table, smth like this:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name_field: { Sequelize.STRING },
  age_field: { Sequelize.INTEGER },
  // other fieds
  userRole: {
    type     : Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    get      : function()  {
      return global.db.Role.findOne({
        // user_id or how it defined in Role table    
        where: {user_id: this.userId}
      }).success(function(role) {
         return role 
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try this soon. I'm currently doing a work around of sorts, but this definitely deserves looking into.